# c - Function to free an array of strings

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, free

## The Backstory:

I created a function to destroy an array of strings in c.

I pass the pointer to the array into this function, first freeing the individual strings, then the array itself.

When I run the program I get the following error:

```
tokenDemo(4967,0x11afeb5c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fde73c02a05:pointer being freed was not allocated
tokenDemo(4967,0x11afeb5c0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

I'm almost certain im passing in the right pointer. What am I missing?

## The Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "token.h"

#define MAXLEN 100

int main(){
  //delimiters used for tokenization
  char sep[4] = {',',' ','\n'};
  char *strin = (char*)malloc(MAXLEN * sizeof(char));
  printf("enter sentence: \n");
  fgets(strin, (MAXLEN + 1), stdin);

  char** tokens = stringToTokens(strin, sep);
  int i=0;
  while(tokens[i] != NULL){
    reverse(tokens[i]);
    printf("%s ",tokens[i]);
    i++;
  }
  printf("\n");

  printf("tokens: %d\n*tokens: %s\n", tokens, *tokens);

  destroyTokens(tokens);

  free(strin);
}




#define MAX 100 //this is the maximim number of words that can be tokenized

char **stringToTokens(char *str, char *sep){
  //malloc space for the array of pointers
  char **tokenArray = (char **) malloc(MAX * sizeof(char*));

  char * token = strtok(str, sep);

  int count = 0;

  while(token!=NULL){
    tokenArray[count] = token;
    count ++; //tracks number of words
    token = strtok(NULL, sep); //gets the next token in the string and sets it to token
  }

  tokenArray[count]=NULL; //adds null to last element

  return tokenArray;
}

void destroyTokens(char **tokenArray){
  //free the individual strings
  int i=0;
  while(tokenArray[i] != NULL){ 
        free(tokenArray[i]);
        i++;
    }
    free(tokenArray);
}

void reverse(char *s){
  int length = strlen(s);
  char *start, *end, temp;

  start=s;
  end=s;

  //now actually move end to the end of the string
  for(int i=0; i<length-1; i++){
    end++;
  }

  for(int i=0; i<length/2; i++){
    temp   = *end;
    *end   = *start;
    *start = temp;

    start++;
    end--;
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also recommend a bit of extra Armour in `stringToTokens` at `while(token!=NULL)` to make sure `count < MAX`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

strtok function does not allocate memory. It returns pointer to char inside passed string. So you should not release memory for it. This part of code:

```
while(tokenArray[i] != NULL){ 
    free(tokenArray[i]);
    i++;
}
```

must be omitted

Comment: Sidenote: Also important that the source of `str`, `strin` in this case, cannot be allowed to be freed, go out of scope, whatever, while the token array is still in use. It may be better to allocate and manage new storage for the tokens in `stringToTokens`. In this case the code should NOT be omitted.

Comment: That's also what I had thought. However, this was included in the instructions of my problem:

This function deallocates the memory allocated for an array of strings, as createdbystringToTokens. Be sure to free each string in addition to the array ofpointers.

Comment: Got it. The answer to the question is correct, however when I deep copy the string like I was directed, I must then deallocate the memory used for the deep copy. 

Thanks!